# getting the saved password in android

Tags: android, preferences

I am creating an android device in which there ia a login activity. how to check whether a certain id and password is saved in android device earlier and if it is saved then when the user has entered the emailid the password should get automatically set  in the password field.
I have saved the email id and password as

```
if ((savepass).isChecked()) {

                    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit()
                        .putString(PREF_USERNAME, eMailId)
                        .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, PWOrd)
                        .commit();
              }
```

can anyone please help me..
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get saved username and PW:

   ```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
   String pw = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);
   String username = pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null);
   ```

   if either is null, then username/password are not saved.
2. Set the password / username in the relevant fields:

   ```
   userNameTextView.setText(username);
   passwordTextView.setText(pw);
   ```